# Search and remove a parameter with optional character from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I'm looking to remove a parameter from a URL with a click event. The issue is that the parameter can either have an `&` before it or not. So the form is either `search=MYSEARCHTERM` or `&search=MYSEARCHTERM`.

I have the following which appears to work fine for one or other but not both. I was thinking that I could have an if / else statement one of which contains something like this. (Excuse the crappy regex but I've never written it before)

`var searchKeywordRegx = new RegExp(/(?:&)/ + 'search=' + searchKeyword);`

```
$('.searchKeyword').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    var searchKeywordRegx = new RegExp('search=' + searchKeyword);
    console.log(searchKeywordRegx);
    document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace(searchKeywordRegx , "" );
});
```

Am I way off base here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?` to make something optional in a regexp:

```
var searchKeywordRegx = new RegExp('&?search=' + searchKeyword);
```

Comment: Ah! so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can do this without regular expressions. If you simply remove that portion of the document location's "search":

```
document.location.search = document.location.search
    .replace('search=' + encodeURI(searchKeyword), '');
```

Comment: I'm heard of encodeURI but I'm not familiar with it. I'll have to check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @LMG, I'm using `encodeURI` because it will ensure that the values have proper encoded strings. For example, if the string was `search=testing this` (with the space), then what is in the URL is `search=testing%20this`. So `encodeURI` makes sure that the value you pass to it will match how it would look in a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.